# Как подключить свои собственные данные для обучения нейросети?

Tags: python

Есть директория, в ней две папки с фотографиями - зимы в одной и лета в другой.

```
C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\train_images
```

Как подключить данные для обучения нейросети? В качестве бэкенда keras использую theano.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можите использвать os.listdir, она вернет все файлы находящиеся в указанной директории.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

path = 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\train_images'
for i in os.listdir(path):
    arr = plt.imread(path +'\\' + i)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но у меня там две папки. А в них уже изображения. Поэтому возникает ошибка: permission denied.

Comment: В чем проблема добавить все массивы изображений в один массив индивидуально для каждой папки, допустим у вас в одной папке изображения с размером 28*28 и их там 10 штук, следовательно вам нужен инициальзованый массив np.empty([28,28*10]) после чего делать шаг для каждого изображения после чего вы можите запиклить массив если вам нужно. Надеюсь изображения одного размера?

Comment: Чуть не забыл, еще существует функция for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(path):

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо, уже сделал на основе примера: отличие кошки от собаки.